# Set selected option based on URL hash with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, url, hash

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
</select>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("mySelect").options.selectedIndex = "2";
    }
</script>
```

This script selects "Pineapple" when the button is clicked. I want to do this exact same thing, except it should be selected immediately on refresh. ALSO, rather than using the `selectedIndex`, I would like to set the selected option based on the URL hash.

So: `myname.com/#this`

`if location.hash == 'this'` then set the option with an equal value as selected.

If it's checking for the `location.hash`, then I shouldn't need to use `onload` because it will pull the information from the url automatically. I know this is simple, I just don't know JavaScript well enough to get it put together myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd generally just listen to the hashchange event

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', fn, false);

window.onload = fn; // fire on pageload

function fn() {
    document.getElementById('mySelect').value = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
}
```

Comment: I tried this like so:
    <script>
window.addEventListener('hashchange', fn, false);

fn(); // fire on pageload

function fn() {
    document.getElementById('mySelect').value = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body dir="ltr">

<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>

It works, except when I reload the page, the option resets back to Apple.

Comment: See the updated code, or place the script tag after the elements in the DOM